# Automate Statement IN SQL Every 5 Minutes

Tags: sql, mariadb, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to automate a Load Data Infile command in MariaDB/SQL (they are the same?) every 5 minutes. This is the block of code i'm trying to automate.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to text file'
INTO TABLE Student
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

I've tried some of the simpler solutions already but to no avail. I was thinking of creating a script and using the built in system scheduler but I'm on linux and not to familiar and would very much prefer a way to do this within MYSQL. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Will it be putting duplicate data in the table every 5 minutes?

Comment: Thought it would but apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I believe MariaDB should include MySQL's event scheduler - you can find more details on use of it here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

I'd suggest putting that code in a stored procedure and using that to fire the process:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stored_proc_name ()
BEGIN
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to text file'
    INTO TABLE Student
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
END
```

Then create the event:

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
DO
    EXEC stored_proc_name
```